# version de threejs supported by autodesk-forge viewer

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

which version of threejs supports forge viewer?
I need to use threejs version 130 or higher, are these versions compatible with forge viewer?

Comment: Why do you need to use r130+?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Forge Viewer uses self-managed three.js r71. Currently, our engineering team is working hard to support the newer three.js. See here for some updates.

https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Forge-Road-Map-2021

However, you may check these two blog posts to know how to leverage newer three.js using the es5 module.

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/consume-aec-data-which-are-model-derivative-api
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-add-newest-threejs-features-forge-viewer